# Large Deformation of Soft Hollow Cylinder With Surface Effects

Tags: applied-mechanics

I have to find the elongation of a hollow cylinder subject to internal pressure and constrained on the external surface. Basically the deformations allowed are only the internal radius deformation and the axial elongation, while the external radius is fixed.
I found this [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/321745387_Large_Deformation_and_Instability_of_Soft_Hollow_Cylinder_With_Surface_Effects) that solves a very similar problem with the only difference that the external radius is not constrained and there is an external pressure p2 acting on the cylinder. How can I adapt their solution to my case? Do I have to change the deformation tensor to take into account the different deformation? Should I replace the boundary condition (17) with a geometric condition for the external radius, so that the pressure p2 will be an unknown of the problem?
Thanks in advance

Comment: the boundary condition is $R_{outside} = constant$ ... more interestingly, the boundary condition for axial forces (eventually producing shear??,) i.e. whether there is friction at the OD